# CodeIgniter .htaccess url works but not with second (method) parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a pretty standard .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

It works just great when I have one parameter. e.g.
This `/mysite/index.php?c=home`
works just like this does `/mysite/home`

This `/mysite/index.php?c=home&m=mymethod`
works just like this does `/mysite/home/mymethod` ... except for loading relative resources.

The url `/mysite/home/mymethod` seems to leave the web browser having a relative path of `/mysite/home` instead of `/mysite/`. When i go to `/mysite/home/mymethod` and I try to load a css, image, or js file with a relative path (e.g. the html says `css/site.css`), the browser appends `home/` to the beginning of the path. Meaning, the web browser tries to load `home/css/site.css` instead of `css/site.css` ... in short the relative path gets hosed when I specify a second parameter.

Why is the relative path wrong when I specify a second uri parameter?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the question is why the relative path is wrong ... the browser wants to load home/css/site.css instead of css/site.css - it only does this when i specify a second parameter (the method aka m= paramter). Is this is a codeigniter config setting or an htaccess problem or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser requests content, and that content has relative links (to css, images, js, etc), it is up to the browser to determine the relative URI **base**. Browsers do this by looking at the URL that it requested. For example, if I type this in the browser's location bar:

```
http://mysite.com/home/mymethod/maybe-a-file.html
```

And the (in this example, static) content that is served from the file `maybe-a-file.html` contains a link to an image:

```
<img src="boo.jpg">
```

So it's up to the browser to determine what the relative URI base is in order to actually request that image. This example is easy. It looks at the requested URL, and removes the last file-node, and it gets:

```
http://mysite.com/home/mymethod/
```

and thus it loads the image at:

```
http://mysite.com/home/mymethod/boo.jpg
```

Simple enough. However, in your case, the browser is loading this URL:

```
http://mysite.com/home/mymethod
```

which isn't a static page, but the browser doesn't know. All it knows is the URL and the content it got back, and it gets content that has this:

```
<img src="boo.jpg">
```

So it looks at the URL and finds a base:

```
http://mysite.com/home/
```

and thus attempts to load the image at:

```
http://mysite.com/home/boo.jpg
```

The browser knows nothing about the content actually being served from `/index.php`. That all happens internally on the server, it only knows the URL that it requested, nothing else.

So in order to fix this, you have to change your relative paths to absolute paths so the browser doesn't incorrectly guess the wrong base URI, or you can specify the base URI so the browser doesn't have to guess. You can do this by adding this to the header of your page(s):

```
<base href="/" />
```

or whatever the base is supposed to be.

Comment: I understand this. It wasn't the answer I was hoping for ... here's the thing, in my dev environment, the site lies in a sub-directory, but in live its in the root. Because of this, I'll have to set the absolute path differently depending on environment. While this is doable (though some work to maintain), I was hoping for some .htaccess magic:) Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @DonDickinson The way CMS's like wordpress deals with this (since you can install it in subdirectories) is that there is a global setting for where the application root is (e.g. `http://mysite.com/mystuff/`) and it simply makes all links absolute based on that setting. If you move it, you need to change the site URL.

Comment: I think my solution will be to eliminate page displays based on the 2nd parameter. that is, I'll use the second parameter if its an ajax call (e.g. /mysite/customer/update), but for things that show a page i'll just use the first parameter. This might be a better way for me to structure the app anyway. Thanks for the advice and taking the time. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

You can use the url helper `$this->load->helper('url')` and use `base_url()` function to get the base path of your site to use on links or including css/js files.